# Export DB with modified primary keys' values. MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I`m merging multiple databases with huge amount of dependencies.
The only (fast) solution I see is to prepend the DB identifier to the primary keys.
For example:

```
1, 2, 3 >>> 7771, 7772, 7773
```

It is impossible to modify PKs. That's why the standard solution (SSMS "Tasks > Generate Scripts..") will not help.

I wrote a script to emulate the standard export process.
The main problem is: my script is not able to recognize the type of columns and apply the correct format to the values.

Here it is:

```
select 
name as [table], substring(column_names, 1, len(column_names)-1) as [columns],
concat('SELECT ', substring(column_names, 1, len(column_names)-1) ,', concat(''INSERT INTO ',name,' (',substring(column_names, 1, len(column_names)-1),') VALUES '',', replace(substring(column_names, 1, len(column_names)-1),',',', '','' , '),') as [sql] FROM ', 

name) as [sql]
from sys.tables as tab
cross apply (
select col.[name]+', ' 
from sys.columns as col 
where tab.object_id = col.object_id 
for xml path ('')) D (column_names)
order by name
```

I would really appreciate it if you can help!

Comment: Seems to me that the biggest hurdle is on the import/merging side.

Comment: Can you insert data through the linked server?